# Can't hide the DIV

Tags: javascript, html

any idea why the div doesn't toggle?
I tried also to recall with html, i think i'm missing something, but i don't know what, to me looks ok, but for sure something is missing,

```
albums.forEach((album) => {
    html += `<div class="user"><h2>User ${album.id} Album</h2>`;
        
    let albumPhotos = photos.filter(p => p.albumId == album.id);
    html += `<div>`
    albumPhotos.forEach(photo => {
      html += `<div id="myDIV">
        <img src="${photo.thumbnailUrl}">
       </div>
 `;
    });
    html += '</div>';
  });
// i call back the container set in html
  let container = document.querySelector(".container");
  container.innerHTML = html;
  let container2 = document.querySelector(".button");
  container.innerHTML = html;
}
// function recall
renderUsers();
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

    </script>
```

Comment: Please fix the [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make this an actual [mcve]

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**

Comment: That’s why the `getElementById()` method is named singular and not plural (: Plus, you can render your code simpler by applying `x.toggleAttribute('hidden')`

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `<div id="myDIV">` for each photo, but you're supposed to have unique ids on the page.
You can't have divs with the same `id` - they should be different. In your case you cloud use `class` and not `id`.

Is this the kind of behaviour you're looking for?

```
<div class="container"></div>
<button class="button" onclick="toggleImages()">Toggles Images</button>

<script>
let html = '';
let albumPhotos = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
html += `<div>`;
albumPhotos.forEach(photo => {
    html += `<div class="myDIV"><p>${photo}</p></div>`;
});
html += '</div>';

let container = document.querySelector(".container");
container.innerHTML = html;
let container2 = document.querySelector(".button");
container.innerHTML = html;

function toggleImages() {
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myDIV");
 for (let elem of x) {
    if (elem.style.display === "none") {
      elem.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      elem.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```